# Change the link colors in Material UI Sidebar (Drawer) in a Reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I tried using different properties in the sidebar style to override the link color but nothing is working.

**Default style/color of Sidebar drawer** (before overriding the style)

[image]

**MySidebar.js**

```js
// MySidebar.js

import { Sidebar } from 'react-admin';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import React from 'react';

const useSidebarStyles = makeStyles({
    drawerPaper: {        
        backgroundColor: '#0c2d48',
        color: '#fff',
    },
});

const MySidebar = props => {
    const classes = useSidebarStyles();
    return (
        <Sidebar classes={classes} {...props} />
    );
};

export default MySidebar;
```

**MyLayout.js**

```js
// MyLayout.js

import React from 'react';
import { Layout } from 'react-admin';
import MySidebar from './MySidebar';

const MyLayout = props => (
    <Layout
        {...props}
        sidebar={MySidebar}
    />
);

export default MyLayout;
```

**Result** (after overriding the default style in MySidebar.js)

[image: Result (after overriding the default style in MySidebar.js)]

As you can see, I'm able to change bg color of the sidebar but not the link colors.

Please help. It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own theme as described here:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#writing-a-custom-theme
and in your theme redefine the colors of all MenuItemLink components:

```
export const lightTheme = {
  ...
  
  overrides: {      
    RaMenuItemLink: {
      root: {
        color: "#c51162",
      },
      active: {
        color: "#ff4081",
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: on using the above code it's giving error: `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'RaMenuItemLink' does not exist in type 'Overrides'`

Comment: I don't use TypeScript, @ts-ignore or the following solution may help you:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365396/how-to-use-material-ui-custom-theme-in-react-with-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Try changing link colors.

```
drawerPaper: {        
        backgroundColor: '#0c2d48',
        color: '#fff',
    },
link: {
       color: '#fff',
     },
```

Update: Instead of `link` you can give it the css class name, by looking at inspect element on the ouput sidebar.

Comment: Sidebar links are <Link> or <a> ?

Comment: I have no idea. It's a Material UI component that's generating the links automatically. from the API endpoints I pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using React-Admin for the sidebar and not the Material UI sidebar directly. So possibly the React-Admin template modified the props of original material Ui and you should take a look inside the react admin sidebar and modify it directly there to get the results. If you apply material UI customization on this one, it might be the reason its not working.

Alternative is to try Material UI Themeing with ThemeProvider and apply the theme, which can overwrite the current styling.

Comment: yes that's the issue. I'm not able to find any documentation about styling the links in react admin.

Comment: In the documentation that's the preferred way they mentioned to override the style of drawer i.e. by creating your own Sidebar component along with it's custom style and then passing it to the Layout component