# How do I add a property to the MUI Link component properly with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Currently, in my `mui-theme.ts` file, I have this declaration:

```ts
const theme = createTheme(globalTheme, {
  components: {
    MuiLink: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { hover: 'lightup' },
          style: {
            transition: 'color 0.15s ease-in-out',
            '&:hover': {
              color: globalTheme.palette.primary[300],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  }
})
```

My intention is to use this like so:

```ts
<Link hover="lightup">linktexthere</Link>
```

This works fine, but it gives me a type error telling me that the property `hover` doesn't exist on type `IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<LinkBaseProps, "classes"> ...`. I've attempted to remedy this by using module augmentation in my `mui-theme.ts`:

```ts
declare module '@mui/material/Link' {
  interface LinkPropsHoverOverrides {
    lightup: true;
  }
}
```

This is not changing anything as far as I can tell; I still get the type error. Is there a way to extend `LinkBaseProps`, or otherwise add the `hover` property to `MuiLink` in a TS-safe way?

Comment: I'm not too good with Typescript, but does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365396/how-to-use-material-ui-custom-theme-in-react-with-typescript

Comment: @C.Helling unfortunately that's more about themeing in general without adding custom properties to elements. Thank you for the research though!

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling a bit myself, however I was able to figure it out.

Based on MUI docs, the Link comp is based on the Typography comp.

**Place the following within your `mui-theme.ts` file**

```
declare module "@mui/material/Typography" {
  interface TypographyPropsVariantOverrides {
    lightup: true;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!