# How to solve this typescript problem with mui useMediaQuery and breakpoints?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I need to do MediaQuery in Mui

```
const theme = useTheme();
  const isDesktop = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("desktop"));
```

my problem text:
`I have problem "Property 'breakpoints' does not exist on type 'Theme'.ts(2339)"`

I use this

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    xs: false;
    sm: false;
    md: false;
    lg: false;
    xl: false;
    mobile: true;
    tablet: true;
    laptop: true;
    desktop: true;
  }
}
```

and have theme in App.tsx

```
const theme = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      mobile: 0,
      tablet: 768,
      laptop: 1024,
      desktop: 2560,
    },
  }
```

I don`t understand how to solve this problem
Help pls.

just help I delete all my trying

Comment: Did you provide your theme type as a module extension of the default theme type for the theme provider? With other words: Take a look at this post please first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365396/how-to-use-material-ui-custom-theme-in-react-with-typescript