# Color Changing Error in MUI Button Component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the button color to yellow using the Material-UI Button component in React, but it is not reflecting the color change on the screen. Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
<Button
  onClick={goToLogin}
  variant="contained"
  color="yellow"
  sx={{
    mt: 2,
  }}
>
  ÜCRETSİZ KAYIT OLUN
</Button>
```

Comment: The color name is the name from your theme, by default the options are: "error", "success", "secondary" . if you want to add new colors to the theme you can follow this: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#custom-colors

Answer (score 0):

You can opt to define your theme colors for example `theme.js`

```
import { yellow, gray, red, /*other color as needed here... */} from '@mui/material/colors';

  export const theme = createTheme({
      // other theme configuration here...
      palette: {
        primary: {
         // other color configuration here...
         main: yellow[500]
        },
        secondary: {
          main: gray[500]
        },
        danger: {
          main: red[500]
        },
      }
    })
```

use your theme in the root file of your react app

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { theme } from '../theme';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App/> // app body here...
    </ThemeProvider>
 </React.StrictMode>
);
```

and use your the color in your button wherever you define it in your app body

```
 <Button variant="contained" color="primary"> ÜCRETSİZ KAYIT OLUN </Button>
```

or

```
   <Button variant="contained" sx={{bgcolor: 'danger.main',color: 'primary.main'}}> ÜCRETSİZ KAYIT OLUN </Button>
```

hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Anyderre's answer works for plain JavaScript. If you are working with TypeScript check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70015052/23491960) from a similar question.

You have to adjust your types to support custom colors other than the ones provided by MUI.

Hope this helps!